# how to prevent viewpager to initialize next view by default in android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have implemented viewpager to show some introduction screens in android App. There are 4 different screens having different animations on it. My problem is that when user is on 0 fragment of viewpager the fragment 1 initialize by default and animation ends in background and when user goes to fragment 1 then there is no animation(as animation has ended when fragment 1 initialized simultaneous with fragment 1) . What I want to do is that when user is on fragment 0 then only fragment 0 should initialize not the next fragment which is fragment 1. and when user goes to fragment 1 then fragment 0 should destroy so that  on sliding back to fragment 0 it should initialize again to show animation. How can I do this.

Answer (score 4):

you might change ViewPAger pages memory limit by

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
```

deafult is 1, so one Fragment/View to the left and to the right will stay in memory.

BUT this is poor practise, viewPager is keeping one Fragment/View on each side for better performance and smooth and immediately scroll possibility. I'm suggesting you to create listener for `ViewPager` which fires animations on scrolled to desired Fragment (not starting animations in `onCreateView`). check [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html), especially `onPageSelected(int position)` method

edit:
Google admits that setting 0 for limit is weak, in newest versions logcat says:

```
Requested offscreen page limit 0 too small; defaulting to 1
```

so you have to use listener for firing animations, it's also better for performance. like you see method you want to use is deprecated by author (Google itself). method from `ViewPager` class

```
public void setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit) {
    if (limit < DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Requested offscreen page limit " + limit + " too small; defaulting to " +
                DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES);
        limit = DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES;
    }
    if (limit != mOffscreenPageLimit) {
        mOffscreenPageLimit = limit;
        populate();
    }
}
```

you might also create own `ViewPager` or change `DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES` or `mOffscreenPageLimit` and fire `populate();` method, all using Reflections, smth like this

```
Field f = ViewPager.class.getDeclaredField("DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES");
f.setAccessible(true);
f.setInt(viewPager, 0);
```

then `setOffscreenPageLimit(0);` should work

Comment: I tried this. its not working
adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(_activityWalkThrough, imageArra);
  view_pager_walk_through.setAdapter(adapter);
  view_pager_walk_through.setOffscreenPageLimit(o);

Comment: correct, setting 0 is "deprecated" (lets say). see my edit above. you might always create your own ViewPager extending the original one, but Google didn't blocked this 0 limit option without reason, it's a bad practise

Comment: Ok let me try with the suggestion you gave above. I will let you konw the status, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use fragment call back onResume like in activity to start the animation.
link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onResume%28%29

Comment: nope, `onResume` is also called for offscreen Fragments, which are in offscreen limit (for not less than 1 there will be min. 3 `onResume`s on Activity start or creation/inflating `ViewPager`, or two if your starting position is 0)

Comment: Then use: OnPageChangeListner Link:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)

Comment: this solution I've suggest in my ans. also @rahul might use Reflections, but it isn't recommended nor proper way to solve his issue